# Auto-updating desktop calendar as wallpaper

Tags: wallpaper, calendar

Is there such an application that updates your wallpaper according to your planner/calendar so that you can have a weekly view of your planner/calendar.

Comment: if your planner/calendar is CLI based, you can try "conky"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **gcalcli** with **Conky**.
You can follow the detailed installation tutorial in [this article](http://xmodulo.com/integrate-google-calendar-linux-desktop.html)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: cool! Thank you so much. Didn't find this when looking at the other questions (yes I did some searching :) )